# How does one rectify money fraud done earlier in his life?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, gezel-stealing, business

If someone was not observant and was involved in fraudulent business deals (selling free ebooks on ebay, or claiming used items are new). Later in life, if this person became an Observant Jew what steps can he take to rectify for these sins?

The victims of these deals are unknown.

Comment: 1) Regret that he did it. 2) Stop doing it. 3) Ask forgiveness from anyone harmed (if applicable). 4) Confess to God (Vidui). 5) Accept never to do it again. (All that done seriously, not just lip-service.)

Comment: "He should use the funds for public-benefit projects" as is codified in Hil. Teshuva. What is the question?

Answer (score 6):

Just to redact the fantastic comments [of DoubleAA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59357/how-does-one-rectify-money-fraud-done-earlier-in-his-life/59362#comment158441_59357) and [of Danny Schoemann](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59357/how-does-one-rectify-money-fraud-done-earlier-in-his-life/59362#comment158456_59357) into a consolidated answer format:

There are the general steps of repentance, namely:

```
1) Regret that he did it.
2) Stop doing it.
3) Ask forgiveness from anyone harmed (if applicable).
4) Confess to God (Vidui).
5) Accept never to do it again.

(All that done seriously, not just lip-service.)
```

The Talmud says that if one can't identify the victims of one's theft (or fraud, I assume), then one should give to public-benefit projects, as that way there's a chance that some victims will benefit. (It should be something that helps *everyone*, not just the poor, unless the victims were all poor.) Maybe the library, volunteer fire department, or the like in whatever towns there are likely to be victims, or if you have no idea, your own town?